# Dynamic Pointer Cast

Tags: c++, inheritance, smart-pointers

I'd like to convert a base class pointer to a derived class pointer as a function argument without using dynamic_pointer_cast

```
class Base 
{
    public:     
    typedef std::shared_ptr < Base > Ptr;
    virtual ~Base ( );
    ...
};

class Derive : public Base
{
    public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr < Derive > Ptr;
    ...
};

void foo( Derive::Ptr ptr )
{
    ... 
}

Base::Ptr ptr1 ( new Derive );
foo( ptr1 );
```

The above code will give an error while calling foo. This can be avoided by typecasting ptr1 into a Dervie pointer using std::dynamic_pointer_cast.

```
Base::Ptr ptr1 ( new Derive );
foo ( std::dynamic_pointer_cast < Derive > ( ptr1 ) );
```

I want to create a map of callback functions that will automatically typecast a base class pointer and call the corresponding function based on the type of derived class.

Comment: You can template the function and do some derived-checking for the base statically, or you can just receive a base class pointer from the smartptr..

Comment: I will have a many derive class types and have a corresponding function that will be a derive class type.

Comment: You can build a dispatch mechanism for `foo` to be dispatched to the appropriate implementation based on the derived class type but it won't be simple.

Comment: @RSahu: or it can be: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2497baf83177a9e0

Comment: @MooingDuck That's slick. Do you mind if I add that to my answer?

Comment: @RSahu: Sure, please do.  It could be optimized to iterate over dispatchers of each derived type, and then call the functions for that particular derived type, which may or may not be be slightly faster, but is much more code.  Probably not worth it, especially for this use-case.  (Note that my code doesn't handle overloaded functions all that well, though that's fixable)

Comment: This implementation is tempting, but it still has to iterate through all the available callback functions. But all my derived classes have type variable, so I can keep a map instead of a vector to avoid iterating.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <memory>

class Base 
{
    public:     
    typedef std::shared_ptr < Base > Ptr;
    virtual ~Base () {}
};

// Dispatch mechanism to dispatch derived class specific
// functions for foo.

// Base class.
struct FooDispatcher
{
   static int registerDispatcher(FooDispatcher* dispatcher)
   {
      dispatcherSet.insert(dispatcher);;
      return 0;
   }

   static void dispatch(Base::Ptr ptr)
   {
      std::set<FooDispatcher*>::iterator iter = dispatcherSet.begin();
      std::set<FooDispatcher*>::iterator end = dispatcherSet.end();
      for ( ; iter != end; ++ iter )
      {
         if ( (*iter)->canProcess(ptr) )
         {
            (*iter)->process(ptr);
            return;
         }
      }
   }

   virtual bool canProcess(Base::Ptr ptr) = 0;
   virtual void process(Base::Ptr ptr) = 0;

   static std::set<FooDispatcher*> dispatcherSet;
};

std::set<FooDispatcher*> FooDispatcher::dispatcherSet;

void foo( Base::Ptr ptr )
{
   FooDispatcher::dispatch(ptr);
}

// A class template for derived classes to use when they
// have an implementation of foo.
template <typename T>
struct FooDerivedDispatcher : public FooDispatcher
{
   virtual bool canProcess(Base::Ptr ptr)
   {
      return (std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(ptr) != nullptr);
   }

   virtual void process(Base::Ptr ptr)
   {
      fooImpl(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(ptr));
   }
};

// Derived1 and its implementation of foo.
class Derived1 : public Base
{
    public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr < Derived1 > Ptr;
};

void fooImpl( Derived1::Ptr ptr )
{
   std::cout << "Came to fooImpl(Derived1::Ptr).\n";
}

// Register the FooDispatcher for Derived1
int dummy1 = FooDispatcher::registerDispatcher(new FooDerivedDispatcher<Derived1>());

// Derived2 and its implementation of foo.
class Derived2 : public Base
{
    public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr < Derived2 > Ptr;
};

void fooImpl( Derived2::Ptr ptr )
{
   std::cout << "Came to fooImpl(Derived2::Ptr).\n";
}

// Register the FooDispatcher for Derived1
int dummy2 = FooDispatcher::registerDispatcher(new FooDerivedDispatcher<Derived2>());

// Test...    
int main()
{
   Base::Ptr ptr(new Derived1);
   foo(ptr);

   ptr = Base::Ptr(new Derived2);
   foo(ptr);
}
```

Output:

```
Came to fooImpl(Derived1::Ptr).
Came to fooImpl(Derived2::Ptr).
```

**Update**

A simpler dispatch mechanism... Thanks to @MooingDuck.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Base 
{
    public:     
    typedef std::shared_ptr < Base > Ptr;
    virtual ~Base () {}
};

struct FooDispatcher {
    template<class Derived, class Func>
    bool registerFunction(Func func) {
        auto lambda = [=](std::shared_ptr<Base>& ptr)->void {
            std::shared_ptr<Derived> d = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(ptr);
            if (d)
                func(std::move(d));
        };
        functions.push_back(lambda);
        return true;
    }
    void dispatch(std::shared_ptr<Base>& ptr)
    {
        for(auto& func : functions)
            func(ptr);
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Base>&)>> functions;
};

FooDispatcher dispatcher;

void foo( Base::Ptr ptr )
{
   dispatcher.dispatch(ptr);
}

class Derived1 : public Base
{
    public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr < Derived1 > Ptr;
};

void fooImpl1( Derived1::Ptr ptr )
{
   std::cout << "Came to fooImpl(Derived1::Ptr).\n";
}

class Derived2 : public Base
{
    public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr < Derived2 > Ptr;
};

void fooImpl2( Derived2::Ptr ptr )
{
   std::cout << "Came to fooImpl(Derived2::Ptr).\n";
}

int main()
{
   dispatcher.registerFunction<Derived1>(fooImpl1);
   dispatcher.registerFunction<Derived2>(fooImpl2);

   Base::Ptr ptr(new Derived1);
   foo(ptr);

   ptr = Base::Ptr(new Derived2);
   foo(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for implementation