# Pointer to base-class as argument of an overloaded function

Tags: c++, overloading

I have the following:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

void foo(Base const &b) { cout << "foo(Base)" << endl; }
void foo(Derived const &d) { cout << "foo(Derived)" << endl; }

/* ... */

Base *bb = new Base();
Base *bd = new Derived();
Derived *dd = new Derived();

foo(*bb);
foo(*bd); // <== calling foo(Base const &)
foo(*dd);
```

The program outputs foo(Base), foo(Base) and foo(Derived). Why is `foo(Base)` called the second time around? How can I rewrite this, to have `foo(Derived)` called the second time? Thanks!

Comment: Re: first question: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658316/why-is-not-overloaded-function-for-derived-class-object-invoked-when-given-a-poi. Re: second question: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#C.2B.2B. (But note that, to get that to work, you need to use *pointers* rather than *references*. `*bd` will slice your object regardless of how you use it.)

Comment: no `(*bd)` won't slice the object, unless you do a copy of that Base object after. E.g. `Base bSlice = *bd;` , that would slice the object for sure.

Comment: For a solution to your problem, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896308/dynamic-pointer-cast/23897264#23897264.

Comment: Why would I need multiple dispatch for this? it's just a single argument that needs its dynamic type evaluated at run-time.

Comment: @RSahu wow, that looks quite complex. So there isn't some obvious language mechanic I'm totally missing?

Comment: @DanNestor The only language mechanism available is to make them virtual member functions. You can use `dynamic_cast` and `if-else` branches to get what you want but such code is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

When you feed `foo()`  with `*bd` , `bd`  is a `Base*` , just like you have defined it:

- `Base *bd =...`

Acordingly, the compiler calls `void foo(Base const&)`.

if you're sure that you can do a downcast, you can call `static_cast<>()`:

- `foo( * static_cast<Derived*>(bd) );`

I find that ugly though.

You could simply use overriding.

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void foo(){ std::cout << "only base and derived classes that don't overide foo"; }
    virtual ~Base(){};
};

struct MyDerived : public Base
{
    virtual void foo(){ std::cout << "only MyDerived calls this function"; }
};

void test()
{
    Base b;
    MyDerived d;

    b.foo(); // prints: only base and derived that don't overide foo
    d.foo(); // prints: only MyDerived calls this function
}
```

Comment: Surely, you mean `dynamic_cast`! :P

Comment: When I'm sure I can downcast, I use `static_cast`. It is aimed precisely at that. If I'm not sure that I can down cast... then yes i would use dynamic_cast, (that returns nullptr if I'm wrong)... but in such case there would be a huge alarm in my head saying "dynamic_cast... Maybe a code smell here!!!!!" : strong coupled programming.

Comment: Anyway, I'm trying to use the dynamic type to select the correct overload - a cast would be counter-productive here.

Comment: At the moment you want `foo(Derived&)` to be called, this implies that your code only feeds `Derived` objects there. If it doesn't, probably you are enforcing too much code paths in the same place. You have to show me more of your code so as I can speak more precisely. The first solution to this is to call a `virtual` function on your class `Base`, that has been overridden in your class `Derived`. That's the purpose of overriding: Derived object will call its own proper version. I'm gonna add a code example in the answer.

Comment: That's right, there are many classes derived from `Base`. I was trying to use their type to choose the right implementation of `foo` to run, but I realize now maybe that's the wrong approach.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` would fail here because the class is not polymorphic

Comment: Unfortunately virtual methods don't help. They would work in the example, but in my code `foo` is actually a method from another class. Is my idea bad to begin with? (Using the dynamic type of the object to choose between different implementations at run-time)

Comment: @MattMcNabb for what reason Base is not polymorphic ? since Derived inherits it ? At the moment you use a Base pointer, you can pass silently a Derived pointer.

Comment: @StephaneRolland that's not polymorphism, it's just inheritance

Comment: @MattMcNabb you mean polymorphism implies that there are virtual functions called upon the base interface...

Comment: @StephaneRolland yes, polymorphism requires at least one virtual function to exist on the base class . A polymorphic base is required in order to be able to determine at runtime whether a `Base*` (or a `Base&`) is actually pointing/referring to a `Derived` object.

Answer (score 0):

In overload resolution, a `Base` is a better match for `Base&` than for `notBase&`.

You seem to want polymorphic behaviour, so you have to make your class polymorphic by including at least one virtual function. (This could be the destructor).

Polymorphism doesn't affect overload resolution either. To get polymorphic behaviour you have to go through a `virtual` function or a `dynamic_cast`.

One option (not a great one, but it is possible) would be to open up `foo` with:

```
void foo(Base const &b)
{
    Derived const *d = dynamic_cast<Derived const *>(&b);
    if ( d ) { foo(*d); return; }
```

The engine linked to by R Sahu is a generalization of this where you register the various derived classes, to avoid having a whole lot of copypasta.

However it is considered better style to use a virtual function. If you don't want to change `foo` to be just one function that invokes `Base` polymorphically, then one way to do this would be:

```
void foo(struct Base const &b);
void foo(struct Derived const &d);

struct Base
{
    virtual void foo_caller() const { foo(*this); }
    // ...
};

struct Derived
{
    virtual void foo_caller() const { foo(*this); }
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    Base *p = new Derived();
    p->foo_caller();
```

Comment: You're basically describing the Visitor pattern, isn't that right?

Comment: @DanNestor I just thought of this now, IDK if it has a name